How to solve too many positional arguments after update on Tensorflow using @tf.function on keras custom model?
I have updated my project to the latest Tensorflow 2.16. When running my DQN network, I have an issue on calling my "policy_net" to return my selected action.
Here is the issue:
 File "/mnt/c/Repository/AILearn/Server/src/algorithms/dqn.py", line 98, in select_action
    return np.argmax(policy_net(state))
  File "/mnt/c/Repository/AILearn/Server/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_filel9dkc_7r.py", line 10, in tf__call
    x = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).input_layer, (ag__.ld(inputs),), None, fscope)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/inspect.py", line 3186, in bind
    return self._bind(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/inspect.py", line 3107, in _bind
    raise TypeError('too many positional arguments') from None
TypeError: Exception encountered when calling Model.call().

in user code:

    File "/mnt/c/Repository/AILearn/Server/src/algorithms/dqn.py", line 32, in call  *
        x = self.input_layer(inputs)
    File "/mnt/c/Repository/AILearn/Server/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler  **
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/inspect.py", line 3186, in bind
        return self._bind(args, kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/inspect.py", line 3107, in _bind
        raise TypeError('too many positional arguments') from None

    TypeError: too many positional arguments


Arguments received by Model.call():
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 22), dtype=float32)

Here is the code of the "select_action" method:
def select_action(self, state, policy_net):
    rate = self.strategy.get_exploration_rate(self.current_step)
    self.current_step += 1

    if rate > random.random():
        return random.randrange(self.num_actions)
    else:
        state = np.atleast_2d(np.atleast_2d(state).astype("float32"))
        return np.argmax(policy_net(state))

And here the "policy_net" keras Model:
class Model(tf.keras.Model):
    """
    Subclassing a multi-layered NN using Keras from Tensorflow
    """

    def __init__(self, num_states, hidden_units, num_actions):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.input_layer = tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(shape=(num_states,))
        self.hidden_layers = []

        for hidden_unit in hidden_units:
            # Left kernel initializer
            self.hidden_layers.append(
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_unit, activation="tanh")
            )

        self.output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_actions, activation="linear")

    @tf.function
    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.input_layer(inputs)
        for layer in self.hidden_layers:
            x = layer(x)
        output = self.output_layer(x)
        return output

I have search in the release note of Tensforlow and I have seen this in the 2.12 release note: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.12.0

tf.function now uses the Python inspect library directly for parsing
the signature of the Python function it is decorated on. This change
may break code where the function signature is malformed, but was
ignored previously, such as: ...

I'm not sure now what is wrong with my code ? And if it was wrong from the beginning ?
Did I miss something ? I didn't save at first my old Tensorflow version. So I have no idea of the change that have impacted my project unfortunately.

You should not have an InputLayer, it is not callable and serves no purpose here.

Hi @xdurch0, can you explain me why ? Is that part of my problem or just a remark to improve my code ?

Well the error points at the self.input_layer(inputs), which fails because that layer does not take any arguments, it's not to be called.

Ok but I don't understand why this code works on older version of Tensorflow... I never seen that issue and what you say make sense. Any idea ?
